Custom Authenticationfilter authentication successful but not logged in
I am using spring boot with hilla and I am trying to implement a custom login since the Form based login doesnt suit my goal.
I've created an AuthenticationProvider, AuthenticationFilter and added them to my WebSecurityConfig.
Looking at the response I'm getting when trying to login it does seem to work, but in further requests im Anonymous again.
AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter::successfulAuthentication takes care of setting the SecurityContext so I dont know what I am missing or what I am doing wrong here.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
SecurityConfig
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends VaadinWebSecurity {
    private final JTicketAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private final RouteUtil routeUtil;
    private final AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration;
    private final UserService userService;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(registry -> registry.requestMatchers(
                routeUtil::isRouteAllowed).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/user/login").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).permitAll());
        http.addFilterAfter(new JTicketAuthenticationFilter(authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager(), userService),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
        super.configure(http);
    }
}

AuthenticationProvider
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JTicketAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        final JTicketAuthentication auth = (JTicketAuthentication) authentication;
        final UserDto user = userService.getUserDtoByEmail(auth.getEmail());
        if (user != null) {
            var userCredential = userService.getUserCredentialById(user.getId());
            if (!user.isCredentialsNonExpired()) {
                throw new ApiException("Credentials are expired. Please reset your password");
            }
            var userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(user, userCredential);
            validAccount.accept(userPrincipal);
            if (encoder.matches(auth.getPassword(), userCredential.getPassword())) {
                return JTicketAuthentication.authenticated(user, userPrincipal.getAuthorities());
            } else {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Email and/or passwords do not match");
            }
        } else {
            throw new ApiException("Unable to authenticate");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(final Class<?> authentication) {
        return JTicketAuthentication.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }

    private final Consumer<UserPrincipal> validAccount = userPrincipal -> {
        if (!userPrincipal.isAccountNonLocked()) {
            throw new LockedException("Your account is currently locked");
        }
        if (!userPrincipal.isEnabled()) {
            throw new DisabledException("Your account is currently disabled");
        }
        if (!userPrincipal.isCredentialsNonExpired()) {
            throw new CredentialsExpiredException("Your password has expired. Please update your password");
        }
        if (!userPrincipal.isAccountNonExpired()) {
            throw new DisabledException("Your account has expired. Please contact administrator password");
        }

    };
}

AuthenticationFilter
@Slf4j
public class JTicketAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    private final UserService userService;

    public JTicketAuthenticationFilter(final AuthenticationManager authManager, UserService userService) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/user/login", HttpMethod.POST.name()), authManager);
        this.userService = userService;
        setAuthenticationSuccessHandler((_, _, _) -> {}); //writing own response
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            LoginRequest user = new ObjectMapper().configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET, true)
                                        .readValue(request.getInputStream(), LoginRequest.class);
            userService.updateLoginAttempt(user.getEmail(), LoginType.LOGIN_ATTEMPT);
            JTicketAuthentication unauthenticated = JTicketAuthentication.authenticated(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword());
            return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(unauthenticated);

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            RequestUtils.handleErrorResponse(request, response, e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
                                            final FilterChain chain, final Authentication authResult)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        final UserDto user = (UserDto) authResult.getPrincipal();
        userService.updateLoginAttempt(user.getEmail(), LoginType.LOGIN_SUCCESS);
        var httpResponse = sendResponse(request, response, user);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        var out = response.getOutputStream();
        var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(out, httpResponse);
        out.flush();
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
    }

    private Response sendResponse(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final UserDto user) {
        return RequestUtils.getResponse(request, Map.of("user", user), "Login Success", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

Logs
2024-11-01T01:06:14.448+01:00 DEBUG 16804 --- [JTicket] [nio-8081-exec-9] o.v.e.s.JTicketAuthenticationFilter      : Set SecurityContextHolder to JTicketAuthentication [Principal=...]
2024-11-01T01:06:14.449+01:00 DEBUG 16804 --- [JTicket] [nio-8081-exec-9] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to /
2024-11-01T01:06:14.454+01:00 DEBUG 16804 --- [JTicket] [nio-8081-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /
2024-11-01T01:06:14.454+01:00 DEBUG 16804 --- [JTicket] [nio-8081-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-11-01T01:06:14.454+01:00 DEBUG 16804 --- [JTicket] [nio-8081-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /

AnonymousAUthenticationFilter::defaultWithAnonymous
    private SecurityContext defaultWithAnonymous(HttpServletRequest request, SecurityContext currentContext) {
        Authentication currentAuthentication = currentContext.getAuthentication();
        if (currentAuthentication == null) {
            Authentication anonymous = createAuthentication(request);
            if (this.logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                this.logger.trace(LogMessage.of(() -> "Set SecurityContextHolder to " + anonymous));
            }
            else {
                this.logger.debug("Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext");
            }
            SecurityContext anonymousContext = this.securityContextHolderStrategy.createEmptyContext();
            anonymousContext.setAuthentication(anonymous);
            return anonymousContext;
        }
        else {
            if (this.logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                this.logger.trace(LogMessage.of(() -> "Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated "
                        + currentAuthentication));
            }
        }
        return currentContext;
    }

currentContext.getAuthentication() does return null and so the context is set to Anonymous
I've tried not returning a custom response and not using "setAuthenticationSuccessHandler" but that also didnt keep me logged in.
I also tried setting the SecurityContext myself, which had the same result

fixed it by setting "SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT" in the session, probably not the cleanest solution but it works.
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        securityContext.setAuthentication(authResult);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", securityContext);

